# How to re-project a map such as "wrld_simpl"?

Tags: r, plot, maps

To plot the global map, I simply use:

```
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
plot(wrld_simpl)
```

It seems that the projection of the plotted map is `WGS84`. How can I change the projection to another projection.

Thanks for any hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `spTransform` from package `rgdal`:

```
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
wrld_transf <- spTransform(wrld_simpl, CRS(" +proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371228 +b=6371228 +units=m +no_defs "))
plot(wrld_transf)
```

Comment: Because the x and y coordinates of wrld_simpl are in the -90 to 90 and -180 to 180 ranges whereas it s not the case of wrld_transf or any other projection that are not `+proj=latlon`.To know the range of coordinates of your new map type `bbox(wrld_transf)`

Comment: If you're not familiar with the mathematics behind reprojections I would strongly recommend not to reproject and to stick with classic latitude/longitude projections.

Comment: There is [GIS.se] to begin with. But what I meant is that projections are not just a change of coordinates system there is a lot of distorsions involved as well, so you cannot really put a raster calculated with the old projection on the new one just by changing its coordinates system.